# Sum of a cell array along the column

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a cell array like <1x74 cell> and each element of the cell is a matrix of 4 X 4. How do I sum up so that I have a final matrix of 4 X 4. I initially did in the following manner:

```
Total = In{1,1}+In{1,2}+In{1,3}+In{1,4}+In{1,5}+In{1,6}+In{1,7}+In{1,8}+In{1,9}+In{1,10}+.....In{1,74};
```

Comment: Instead of using a cell array, consider using a 74x4x4 matrix. It's faster and you can apply sum directly without loops

Comment: @Daniel. I would be blessed if you can manage to provide the help via code.

Comment: How is the cell originally created? Can you create a 3d matrix instead? If you don't know include the code to your question.

Comment: Sir, I have created an another question which is the complete set of my problem statement. Here's the link for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34825855/sample-covariance-matrix-estimation-for-the-entire-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Total = zeros(2,2);

for i=1:size(In,2)
    Total = Total+In{1,i};
end
display('This is the result: ')
Total
```

As you mentioned  in the comments, if you don't want to define Total in prior, do this

```
for i=1:size(In,2)
    if i~=1 
    Total = Total + In{1,i}; % executes for numbers equal or larger than 2
    else
    Total = In{1,i}; %executes on i=1
    end
end
```

Comment: thank you for your kind help. Is there any way where I can avoid `Total=zeros(2,2)` because this would create problem when I have to do further processing. Your code works fine. Thank you once again.

Comment: There are some  shortcuts such as Total=zeros(size(I{1,1}). There are other ways to do that.

Comment: Upon executing the second code, it is giving error as `Undefined function or variable 'Total'`

Comment: yes, you are right, change == to ~= in the second line. Thank you

Comment: thank you sir for your kind help. I am so grateful for your help. Thank you once again. There is one more question I have added which is my complete problem statement. Here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34825855/sample-covariance-matrix-estimation-for-the-entire-image

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you create a 74x4x4 3D matrix instead of a cell array, you can simply use `sum`

```
Total=sum(In);
```

It will result in a 1x4x4 matrix, to get a 4x4 matrix use `shiftdim`

```
Total=shiftdim(sum(In))
```